# UITextField won't change text color properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, textcolor

I have a `UITextField` that is an address bar for a web browser. When the user loads a page and the page finishes loading, I want the textfield to change the text color to dark gray. It does this just fine. However, when the user edits the textfield again I want the text color to change back to black. Using the `-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method I try to change the color by using `addressBar.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];` but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set the delegate of the text field so the method is called?

Comment: i dont't think i did. ill go back and check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` getting called? If not, you need to set your text field's delegate to the class that implements this method.

Is `addressBar` set to your text field at the time the delegate method is being called?

Try using NSLog to debug.

Comment: in the method, i check for the address bar as the textfield but i think you may be right about setting the delegate of the textfield. I don't think i've done that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution that might work better on iOS 7 and up.

If your UITextView contains text that is detected to be address/phone number/etc, you've got to set tintColor to change text colour of detected items, like this:

```
self.tvPhone.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: This question was answered two years ago. As I stated in comment to the accepted answer, I had not set the delegate of the textField.